# Knockout JS - Checkbox databind

Tags: knockout.js

I'm creating a checkbox that is bind to a property, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: hasSurname, enable: verified()"/>
```

And this works fine. My problem is that i also want that to uncheck the checkbox when the user is not verified, so i do the next:

```
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: hasSurname && verified(), enable: verified()"/>
```

This option has the correct behavior, but the hasSurname property never changes remaining false.

Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binding with value and checked only updates the observable when the widget change status if the expression evaluates to an observable with a "writing" behaviour.

If you want to use a complex expression for reading (*hasSurname() && verified()*) and change a simple value (only *hasSurname*) you will need to make a computed observable with a "write" callback - see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html - in particular the section about writeable computed observables.

Comment: Thanks, i can do what i want with computedObservables. But, i think that should be an easy way, i mean, it is very common that you have a two checkboxes, the first one (verified) enables the second one, an when the first one is not checked, the second one should be disabled and unchecked. i´m doing something wrong? computedObservables  are the only way?

Comment: Well, just out of my mind i think you could also subscribe to the verified observable and reset the hasSurname one when the value is false, and only use verified on the second checkbox to enable/disable it, but i don't think it would be much simpler than the other solution...

Answer (score 1):

I've had mixed results trying to use && inside of a data-bind.  If I need logic like that I encapsulate it in a computed observable.

```
this.validate1And2 = ko.computed(function () {
    var result;
    result = this.hasSurname() && this.verified();
    return result;
}, this);
```

See this jsFiddle for an example (I believe this is the behavior you were looking for).

http://jsfiddle.net/FwUzc/

Update:
I changed the example so it only has 2 checkboxes, and the hasSurname value updates when the verified value changes.
http://jsfiddle.net/FwUzc/2/